# variable in BeautifulSoup find() method is not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup in python3.6. I am not getting an error while using a string as a parameter in the find method.

```
bs.find('div',attrs={'class' : 'ptag'}).text
```

but i am getting error while using variable instead of string directly.

```
bs.find('div',{'class' : ptagclass})
```

**Error:**

```
data=(bs.find('div',{'class' : ptagclass}).text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem relies upon in the way you are trying to find the parameter, try replacing

`bs.find('div',{'class' : ptagclass})`

with

`bs.find('div',{'class' : "ptagclass"})` this should solve the issue.

Hope this helps